# Python array to array2d

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

How do in Python the java code below?

```
    double[] Y = {3.8, 1.67, 1.8, 5.0, 1.5};
    double[][] X = new double[Y.length][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
        X[i][0] = Y[i];
    }
```

I need variable Y as array2d to use in sklearn function.

Comment: Check out arrays in the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say, you have a list:

```
list_a = [ 3.8, 1.67, 1.8, 5.0, 1.5 ];
```

You can do:

```
list_b = [[val for val in list_a]]
```

Comment: Or just `list_b = [list_a]`

Comment: Yes, but then try this code: `list_a = [ 3.8, 1.67, 1.8, 5.0, 1.5 ];list_b = [list_a];list_a.append(0.);print(list_b)` . You will see, that whenever you modify `list_a`, `list_b` will also change as the content of `list_b` is a link to `list_a` by Python. Therefore, it is much safer to use my answer, when you do not want `list_b` changing whenever you modify `list_a`.